# Duvida referente a circular reference do tipo cliente <-> sala

Tags: delphi

Bem, eu tinha perguntado mas acho que não ficou claro então irei editar como sugeriram, basicamente eu queria fazer uma aplicação em Delphi usando uma classe TSala e várias classes TPessoa, porém, a classe TPessoa precisa se referenciar a TSala para poder pegar informações dela e a modifica-la quando for necessário, e a classe sala precisa de uma referência a classe TPessoa para poder criar uma lista de pessoas na sala e poder modificar essas pessoas.

Por exemplo:
Fazer algo assim em algum lugar da classe TPessoa:

```
self.sala.pegarPessoaPorNome("Alberto").Dar("Refrigerante");
```

Já na classe TSala teria algo assim:

```
function pegarPessoaPorNome(nome: string): TPessoa;
begin
 for pessoa in self.pessoas do
  if pessoa.nome = nome then Exit(pessoa);
end;
```

Porém, aí vem o problema, já que essas duas classes estão em units separadas, iria dar um erro no compilador de "referência circular" por eu estar usando a classe TSala na classe TPessoa e a classe TPessoa na classe TSala..
Como eu poderia arrumar isso sem ter que apelar pra pointer ou TObject?

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi claramente oque você precisa. Mas seu problema pode ser resolvido com ObjectList<T>. Oque acontece é que com ObjectList a sua classe TPessoa vai pertencer a TSala, ou seja, voce vai passar a ter uma ListaSala.ListaPessoa. Se concordar com a ideia, posso montar um protótipo de como ficaria.

Comment: Victor Tadashi, eu não entendi foi nada nessa pergunta, se for isso que você entendeu ate que vai, mas se não for isso ai, tenho que estudar mais!

Comment: Daniel Yohan, explica para que você precisa disso ai, no mínimo uma explicação do uso, se não sua pergunta vai ser fechada, se não for possível replicar o erro/problema, logo este não existe. Explique a necessidade, talvez possamos lhe ajudar de outra forma!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto, neste caso, é voce criar a classe TSala como uma collection de TPessoa (ou, a classe sala possui um field que aponta para essa collection)

Voce pode polpar um bocado de código se já fizer suas classes herdando dos types já definidos TCollection e TCollectionItem.

interface
  uses System.Classes;

```
TYPE
TPessoa=Class;{note aqui uma pré-declaração. Permite usar TPessoa em TSala antes de implementa-la}
TSala=Class(TCollection)
public function add:TPessoa;
function pegarPorNome(Nome:String):TPessoa;
property Pessoa(Const Nome:String):TPessoa read pegarPorNome;
constructor create(ItemClass:TCollectionItemClass);
end;

TPessoa=Class(TCollectionItem)
  Nome:String;
  //demais variaveis
  procedure DarQualquerCoisa();
  procedure FazerQualquerCoisa();
end;

implementation

{ TSala }

function TSala.add: TPessoa;
begin
Result := inherited Add as TPessoa;
end;

constructor TSala.create(ItemClass: TCollectionItemClass);
begin
 inherited Create(ItemClass);
end;

function TSala.pegarPorNome(Nome: String): TPessoa;
begin
result := nil;  //se nao encontrar o nome, retorna vazio
for I := 0 to Count-1 do
   begin
     if TPessoa(Items[i]).Nome=Nome then
     begin
     result := Items[i] as TPessoa;
     break;
     end;
   end;
if result = nil then
  showmessage(format('Nome "%s" não encontrado.',Nome));//Nao encontrou esse nome, voce pode emitir um aviso.
end;

{ TPessoa }

procedure TPessoa.DarQualquerCoisa();
begin
;
end;
procedure TPessoa.FazerQualquerCoisa();
begin
;
end;
```

Por fim, como usar esta classe

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Sala1 := TSala.Create;//Sala1 deve ser uma variavel publica
end;
```

Voce pode criar pessoas de duas formas

```
procedure TForm1.BotaoAddPessoa1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Nova_Pessoa:TPessoa;
begin
 Nova_Pessoa:=Sala.Add;
 Nova_Pessoa.Nome := Edit1.Text;
 //... etc
 Nova_Pessoa.FazerQualquerCoisa();
 Nova_Pessoa.DarQualquerCoisa();
end; 

procedure TForm1.BotaoAddPessoa2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//esse é o jeito mais interessante,pois nao precisa declarar variavel
 With Sala.Add do begin
   Nome := Edit1.Text;
//... etc
 FazerQualquerCoisa();
 DarQualquerCoisa();
 end;

end;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Esqueci de limpar da memória, exemplo usando With

 With Sala.Add do begin
   Nome := Edit1.Text;
//... etc
 FazerQualquerCoisa();
 DarQualquerCoisa();
Free;